# Group collections into unique sets

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, icollection

I have data in which needs sorting into individual sets based on having unique id's per set.

For instance I am starting with the below (its actually a pending sql query, but making up the below as an illustrative example):

```cs
IQueryable<DataType> data = [
    {id: 1, description: "some description1", state: 1, associateId: 5}
    {id: 2, description: "some description2", state: 1, associateId: 6}
    {id: 3, description: "some description3", state: 1, associateId: 7}
    {id: 4, description: "some description4", state: 2, associateId: 5}
    {id: 5, description: "some description5", state: 1, associateId: 6}
    {id: 6, description: "some description6", state: 1, associateId: 5}
]
```

And I need it as:

```cs
IQueryable<DataType>[] sortedData = [
[
    {id: 1, description: "some description1", state: 1, associateId: 5},
    {id: 2, description: "some description2", state: 1, associateId: 6},
    {id: 3, description: "some description3", state: 1, associateId: 7}
],
[
    {id: 4, description: "some description4", state: 2, associateId: 5}
],
[
    {id: 5, description: "some description5", state: 1, associateId: 6},
    {id: 6, description: "some description6", state: 1, associateId: 5}
]
```

I need a solution which will continue to stitch to the sql query and not call the data into memory for processing.

Grouping by `state` would only give me two groupings. I need to have unique entities in each grouping based on the associatedId, without a loop (eg bringing into memory).

I feel like I need to apply Distinct somehow, but cant see where.

Comment: It seems you need to add `associateId` to your grouping element and then take 1 of each group. Also need to mention that group-take operations may not work depending on your provider.

Comment: Your example isn't very clear: SQL has no ordering, so why do you have ids 5 & 6 in a separate group from ids 1,2,3? It looks like with the order of the data, you could just split on state value change...

Comment: Can't be done by LINQ, which is always translated into  standard (mostly ANSI) SQL, which is set-based, and therefore not sequence-aware.